# How to remove value and reassign remaining values to keys in array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The below code,

```
$test_array = array("a","b","c","d","e");
echo "<fieldset><pre>";
htmlspecialchars(print_r($test_array));
echo "</pre></fieldset>";
```

which gives output like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
)
```

I want to remove a specific entry say from index 2 and re-index the array as below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => d
    [3] => e
)
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`array_splice`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
array_splice($test_array, 2, 1);
```

The second argument is your index that you want to nix and the third is how many elements you want gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
unset($test_array[2]);
$test_array = array_values($test_array);
```